# WordPress - Breadcrumb NavXT Showing Home Page Twice

Tags: wordpress, breadcrumbs

I've put the Breadcrumb NavXT breadcrumb plugin on my website and whatever page I go to, I get a duplicate of the homepage title. For example, when I got the *FAQ* page of the website, my homepage title is duplicated, but correctly it should display *Homepage Title > FAQ*, but instead it displays *Homepage Title > Homepage Title*.

[image]

[image]

This also happens on a custom post type I made named *Products*. When I go to a single product page, I still get *Homepage Title > Homepage Title*.

[image]

[image]

Anyone know what's wrong with the plugin? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Please review your menu and also visit https://kriesi.at/support/topic/breadcrumb-duplicate/

Comment: I think there is issue in menu. Title is being repeated.

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with a custom post type script I had put in my `functions.php` which was to grab the telephone number of the company. It was conflicting with the slugs on the website.

Sorry about this guys. Thanks for taking the time to answer Ishtiaq appreciate it.